# How do I make a container of images move left or right depending on where the mouse is in the container?

Tags: html, css, transform, mouseover, translate

I have a container of images that I would like to move slightly left or right depending on where the mouse is moving in the container. To illustrate my desired outcome, here is the website I am trying to base this off of: https://kuon.space/#top . Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="space-container">
    
    <img src="images/planets/137-1375528_top-earth-clip-art-free-clipart-spot-earth-removebg-preview.png" class="center-image">

    
    <img src="images/planets/hdstar4-removebg-preview.png" data-speed="2" class="star-image">
    <img src="images/planets/hdstar4-removebg-preview.png" data-speed="3" class="star-image">
    <img src="images/planets/hdstar4-removebg-preview.png" data-speed="-9" class="star-image">
    <img src="images/planets/hdstar4-removebg-preview.png" data-speed="6" class="star-image">
    <img src="images/planets/hdstar4-removebg-preview.png" data-speed="-5" class="star-image">

    <img src="images/planets/hdplanet1-removebg-preview.png" data-speed="5" class="surrounding-image">
    <img src="images/planets/hdplanet2-removebg-preview.png" data-speed="4" class="surrounding-image">
    <img src="images/planets/hdplanet3-removebg-preview.png" data-speed="-4" class="surrounding-image">
    <img src="images/planets/hdplanet4-removebg-preview.png" data-speed="7" class="surrounding-image">
    
    <img src="images/planets/hdplanet5-removebg-preview.png" data-speed="2" class="surrounding-image">
   
    
</div>
```

I tried using the CSS :hover property for my image classes, but I can only move them left or right when hovered over. I can't move the left or right depending on where the mouse hovers over them on. Here is my CSS code:

```
/* Planets Styles */
.center-image{
    width:15%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.surrounding-image{
    width:15%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.space-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
  

.space-container:hover{
    transform: translateX(100px);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: You can use the browser dev tools to check exactly how that webpage is doing it, but I can tell you that some JavaScript is almost certainly going to be required.  Look into the `transform: translate3d` CSS property as well as how to subscribe to the `pointermove` event.  Alternatively, I have seen CSS-only demos of things like this before that use a bazillion tiny overlayed elements along with some clever selectors to accomplish a similar effect, although I'm 100% sure you could do it for this example.

Comment: EDIT:  I'm *NOT* 100% sure that you could do it for this example

Comment: this is something more complex than pure html and css